# No longer invalidateIntrinsicContentSize() invokes intrinsicContentSize for UICollectionViewCell/UITableViewCell in iOS 16?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've used `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()` in UICollectionViewCell to calculate custom UI. But it doesn't invoke `intrinsicContentSize` on iOS beta 16 devices..

```
class DynamicCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    func invokeResize() {
        cell.subviews.forEach { $0.resize() }

        // it doesn't invoke intrinsicContentSize from iOS 16 beta ?? 
        invalidateIntrinsicContentSize() 
    }

    override func intrinsicContentSize: CGSize { 
        return calculateDynamicCellSize()
    }
}
```

I don't know if it is a bug or a specification that occurred while implementing `UICollectionView.selfSizingInvalidation` property

I could revise this code for iOS beta 16 using parent's( `UICollectionReusableView` | `UIView` ) methods like below.

```
class RevisedDynamicCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    func invokeResize() {
        cell.subviews.forEach { $0.resize() }

        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            // It works because it called UIView.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize 
            invalidateUIViewIntrinsicContentSize()
        } else {
            invalidateIntrinsicContentSize() 
        }
    }

    override func intrinsicContentSize: CGSize { 
        return calculateDynamicCellSize()
    }
}

extension UICollectionReusableView {
    func invalidateUIViewIntrinsicContentSize() {
        super.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! Did you find a fix for it?

Comment: I just use parent's method instead of UICollectionViewCell's. It works